# И еще по оформлению диалогов

Tags: пунктуация

И другой вопрос.
Бывает так, что в монологе какого-то персонажа надо несколько раз уточнить какие-то его действия или изменение мимики и интонаций. Например:
*-Прямая речь, - слова автора, - прямая речь, - слова автора, - прямая речь.*
Не будет ли это выглядеть слишком громоздно? Или лучше оформить так:
*-Прямая речь, - слова автора.

-Прямая речь (того же персонажа), - слова автора.*?
И допустимо ли такое оформление вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что в этом случае следует применить схему с двумя глаголами со значением высказывания, при этом есть возможность уточнить мимику, интонацию, например:

«Любовь... – повторила она медленно и вдруг прибавила: – Я потому и не люблю этого слова, что оно для меня слишком много значит».

Оформление с чередованием  прямой речи и слов автора используется, но при этом после каждой пары ставится точка, например:

- Я предупреждаю тебя! - угрожающе произнес он, склонившись к Гарри, и лицо его побагровело. - Я предупреждаю тебя, мальчишка, если ты что-то выкинешь, что угодно, ты просидишь в своем чулане взаперти до самого Рождества!

— Нынешняя молодежь больно хитра стала, — заметил Базаров и тоже засмеялся. — Прощайте, — заговорил он опять после небольшого молчания. — Желаю вам окончить это дело самым приятным образом; а я издали порадуюсь.